# Patterns / Problems that use dynamic types, dynamic objects and expando objects in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I have recently become aware of the dynamic keyword after doing some digging into Dynamic Objects and Expando Objects in C#

I can appreciate that it is quite cool however apart from a ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC I am struggling to find applications for use.

So I am looking for any design patterns that can use Dynamic and Expando objects or examples of problems that can be elegantly solved using dynamic objects....

Comment: Integration with languages that do not have a strict type system would be one example.